# Flexbox Layout with Embedded Scrolling Divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create this layout with flexbox:
[image]

I can't get the `Left` box to scroll with `overflow-y:scroll`. Instead, the whole viewport scrolls.

I put all the code [in a CodePen here](https://codepen.io/cliftonlabrum/pen/bGpKzbO).

Here's the basic structure:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="attic">
    <h4 contenteditable="true" placeholder="Task title...">Attic (this is an editable title so the text can wrap and this div can grow in height)</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="split">

    <!-- Left Side -->
    <div id="main">
      <div id="notes">
        <p>Notes - this pane should scroll.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="basement">
        Basement
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Right Side -->
    <div id="side">
      Side
    </div>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

And here are my style definitions:

```
#wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100vh;
}
#attic{
  min-height:60px;
  background:#F2F2F2;
}
#split{
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex;
}
#main{
  display:flex;
  background:#CCF5FF;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#notes{
  background:#E2F9D4;
  min-width:440px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#basement{
  height:50px;
  background:#EEE;
}
#side{
  background:#B3F0DD;
  min-width:300px;
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason to use flex instead of grid? looks like a grid will simplify your markup and style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is min-height calc(100vh - [NUMBER]px)
100vh is mean 100% from view port height of window
edit of code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#attic{
  min-height:60px;
  background:#F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
#split{
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex;
}
#main{
  display:flex;
  background:#CCF5FF;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#notes{
  background:#E2F9D4;
  min-width:440px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  border: 1px solid #080;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 114px);
}
#basement{
  height:50px;
  background:#EEE;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
#side{
  background:#B3F0DD;
  min-width:300px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 62px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="attic">
    <h4 contenteditable="true" placeholder="Task title...">Attic (this is an editable title so the text can wrap and this div can grow in height)</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="split">
    <!-- Left Side -->
    <div id="main">
      <div id="notes">
        <p>Notes - this pane should scroll.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="basement">
        Basement
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Right Side -->
    <div id="side">
      Side
    </div>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, there is one bug. If the `attic` has lots of text and its height grows, the `calc(100vh - 114px);` value is no longer accurate because the combined height of the `attic` and `basement` is greater than `114px`.

Comment: you are welcome @CliftonLabrum You have the tools, make them appropriate to the current state of the clamp .. Change the px values according to the site

Answer (score 1):

Setting `overflow: hidden;` to the `#split` element enables the scroll for the `#notes` element, but I'd suggest you use a grid instead of multiple nested flex (both markup and css will be a lot cleaner).

EDIT: you may want to add `flex-basis: 100%;` to the `#notes` element so it uses as much space as it can even if content is shorter

EDIT2: I would also suggest you use `flex-basis: 60px` instead of `height: 60px` for the attic (similar for the basement) to size elements inside flex containers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't heard about `flex-basis`, so I'll look it up.

Comment: have you tried the two lines of code from my answer? using `calc` seems overcomplicated (usually you don't need calc for flex children, flex can handle all the sizing)

Comment: Yes, I changed the heights to use `flex-basis` and it still doesn't behave as intended. I'll keep fiddling with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make your main container `overflow-y:hidden`. To make your Basement always stay at the bottom, make your Notes section grow using `flex-grow`. Later set a height to Sides section and overflow-y using `height:90vh;overflow-y:scroll;`. Here `90vh` is just a guess height. For more accurate value it shud be `100vh - ${Attic height}`

```css
#wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
#attic{
  min-height:60px;
  background:#F2F2F2;
}
#split{
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex;
}
#main{
  display:flex;
  background:#CCF5FF;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#notes{
  background:#E2F9D4;
  min-width:440px;
  height:calc( 90vh - 50px );
  flex-grow:1;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#basement{
  align-content:flex-end;
  height:50px;
  background:#EEE;
}
#side{
  background:#B3F0DD;
  min-width:300px;
  height:90vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="attic">
    <h4 contenteditable="true" placeholder="Task title...">Attic (this is an editable title so the text can wrap and this div can grow in height)</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="split">

    <!-- Left Side -->
    <div id="main">
      <div id="notes">
        <p>Notes - this pane should scroll.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="basement">
        Basement
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Right Side -->
    <div id="side">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My expectation is that the `Basement` will stick to the bottom of the screen all the time, and the `Notes` section will stretch to fill the vertical space available. I should have made that clearer, sorry.